# Trying to put color on part of object

Tags: materials, objects, edit-mode

[image: pok]

I'm trying to make pokemon but I have some problem, i use circle select tool - C in edit mode to select part of object and then I put white color on that part but there are just some stains on the character and not the entire white circuit. Can someone help me, I don't know what to use.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some [coincident geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), but it's hard to tell what's causing it. It's quite possible that you have two copies of the same thing there, one of which is getting the material you want, and the other is covering it up. Right-click and drag on that model to make sure there's not another one underneath it.

Make sure that you're doing your selection in wireframe mode (not shaded), so that you're certain you're getting all the vertices. Keep in mind that you'll have to DEselect any vertices on the opposite side of the model, that you don't want to use that material.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I was working in solid mode. Now it is all good! Thank you. You're the best!

Comment: Glad it worked!